# Get URL from JEditorPane with HyperlinkListener

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink

Hi i'm having a problem getting the URL from a JEditorPane that is setup in HTML using a HyperlinkListener, I've checked many stack questions on the problem but none of them seem to solve it, I've reduced the code down as far as I possibly can and still get the error. When I use the getURL() method it returns null and the getDescription() method returns the string "url" when I want it to return "https://www.google.com", I assume I'm just missing something very obvious

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;


public class View extends JFrame {

    private String urls = "<a href=\"url\">https://www.google.com</a>";
    private JEditorPane textArea;

    public View() {
        super("Test");
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textArea = new JEditorPane();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setContentType("text/html");
        textArea.setEditorKit(JEditorPane.createEditorKitForContentType("text/html"));
        textArea.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        textArea.setEnabled(true);
        textArea.setText(urls);
        textArea.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                if(e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                   System.out.println(e.getURL());
                   System.out.println(e.getDescription());
                }
            }
        });
        add(textArea);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't with your `HyperlinkListener` or the information of the `HyperlinkEvent`

The problem is with your source HTML, take a moment to really look over it...

```
<a href=\"url\">https://www.google.com</a>
```

Can you see why it's printing `url`?  The problem is, the `HyperlinkEvent` is giving you the `href` (and possible what would also be the `description`) attributes, not the text of the element.

So, based on that, your code is working fine.

However, if you actually want to return `www.google.com`, you need to change your source HTML to something more like `<a href=\"https://www.google.com\">Google me</a>"`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private String urls = "<a href=\"https://www.google.com\">Google me</a>";
    private JEditorPane textArea;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame test = new Test();
        test.pack();
        test.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Test() {
        super("Test");
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textArea = new JEditorPane();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setContentType("text/html");
        textArea.setEditorKit(JEditorPane.createEditorKitForContentType("text/html"));
        textArea.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        textArea.setEnabled(true);
        textArea.setText(urls);
        textArea.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                    System.out.println(e.getURL());
                    System.out.println(e.getDescription());
                }
            }
        });
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
    }
}
```

This will print out

```
https://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel completely ashamed about getting the HTML wrong!

Comment: Html's not "real" coding ;P